# Is there a way to handle the first lapply element differently? or prepend it to the lapply result?

Tags: r

Is there a way to handle the first `lapply` element differently? or prepend it to the `lapply` result on the subsequent elements?

For example, I have the following:

```
mapping <- c("a", "b", "c")
# this doesn't matter here
#names(mapping) <- c("aa", "bb", "cc")
xmlvec <- c('<item a="1" c="2" />',
            '<item b="3" c="4" />',
            '<item a="5" b="6" c="7"/>')


df <- as.data.frame(do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(xml_children(read_xml(paste("<xml>", paste(xmlvec, collapse=""), "</xml>"))),
         function(x) {
           y <- xml_attrs(x)[mapping]
           if (any(is.na(names(y)))) {
             y <- y[-which(is.na(names(y)))]
           }
           y[setdiff(mapping, names(y))] <- NA
           y[order(factor(names(y), levels=mapping))]
         }
  )
), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
```

I'd like the first `lapply` element to be handled in such a way and all the subsequent ones only like this:

```
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(xml_children(read_xml(paste("<xml>", paste(xmlvec, collapse=""), "</xml>"))),
         function(x) {
           xml_attrs(x)[mapping]
         }
  )
), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
```

The expected output for both cases (doing the bigger processing first or for every element) must be:

```
     a   b  c
1    1 <NA> 2
2 <NA>    3 4
3    5    6 7
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output? Is it one with 3 columns or 4 columns ?

Comment: 4 columns where? I only have 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just worked out a solution that does what I wanted in a clean way without code duplicates:

```
# read the xml children
xml <- xml_children(read_xml(paste("<xml>", paste(xmlvec, collapse=""), "</xml>")))
xml
# process the first element separately
y <- xml_attrs(xml[[1]])[mapping]
if (any(is.na(names(y)))) {
  y <- y[-which(is.na(names(y)))]
}
y[setdiff(mapping, names(y))] <- NA
y <- y[order(factor(names(y), levels=mapping))]
y
# process the remaining elements in lapply prepending the first
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(
  rbind,
  c(list(y),
    lapply(xml[2:length(xml)],
           function(x) {
             xml_attrs(x)[mapping]
           }
    )
  )
), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function

```
first_fun <- function(xmlvec) {
   as.data.frame(do.call(
     rbind,
     lapply(xml_children(read_xml(paste("<xml>", paste(xmlvec, collapse=""), "</xml>"))),
       function(x) {
         y <- xml_attrs(x)[mapping]
         if (any(is.na(names(y)))) {
           y <- y[-which(is.na(names(y)))]
         }
         y[setdiff(mapping, names(y))] <- NA
         y[order(factor(names(y), levels=mapping))]
       }
   )
   ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

rest_fun <- function(xmlvec) {
   as.data.frame(do.call(
      rbind,
       lapply(xml_children(read_xml(paste("<xml>", paste(xmlvec, collapse=""), "</xml>"))),
       function(x) {
         xml_attrs(x)[mapping]
       }
    )
  ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

Since `rest_fun` returns columns with `NA` as column name we need to adjust the column name based on `first_fun`

```
df1 <- first_fun(xmlvec[1])
df2 <- rest_fun(xmlvec[-1])
names(df2) <- names(df1)
rbind(df1, df2)

#     a    b c
#1    1 <NA> 2
#2 <NA>    3 4
#3    5    6 7
```